# Is it possible to use weblogic Apache plugin 2.2 in order to setup Apache http server 2.4?

Tags: apache, weblogic, httpd.conf, http-proxy, httpserver

I just want to know if it is compatible or not? I loaded the weblogic module in Apache config file and was trying to compile it. But it thrown an error which says that the module is not found but I checked it manually the module was there. Have you guys ever did this kind of setup with different versions? I did with the same versions and worked perfectly.

Comment: Please add details on what module you added, the error you see, etc.

Comment: I was trying to add mod_so.wl